# Why is this double comparison giving an overflow error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

I am trying to compare a double in VBA to make sure it is between two numbers. For some reason it is giving an overflow, not sure why. I originally tried declaring `BeginRange` As a double and doing `BeginRange = 0#` but that only moved the overflow error to earlier in the code.

```
Sub Main()
    
    Dim ZValues As Collection
    Set ZValues = New Collection
    Dim AvgTemps As Collection
    Set AvgTemps = New Collection
    
    Dim Temps As Worksheet
    Set Temps = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temps")
    
    Dim TempsToSum As Collection
    Set TempsToSum = New Collection
    Dim ZValuesToSum As Collection
    Set ZValuesToSum = New Collection
    
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
        CurrentRow = 2
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Temps.Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row
    BeginRange = 0#
    Do Until CurrentRow > LastRow
        Dim CurrentZValue As Double
        CurrentZValue = Temps.Cells(CurrentRow, 3)
        CurrentTempValue = Temps.Cells(CurrentRow, 5)
        If CurrentZValue > BeginRange And CurrentZValue < BeginRange + 0.0015 Then
            ZValuesToSum.Add CurrentZValue
            TempsToSum.Add CurrentTempValue
            CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
        Else
            BeginRange = BeginRange + 0.0015
            ZValues.Add TemptsToSum
            AvgTemps.Add ZValuesToSum
        End If
    Loop
    Stop
    Set AvgTemps = GetAverages(TempsToSum)
    Set ZValues = GetAverages(ZValuesToSum)
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: @BigBen the line that throws the error is the `If CurrentZValue > BeginRange And CurrentZValue < BeginRange + 0.0015 Then` line

Comment: Where is BeginRange declared?  What are the variables values when it errors?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I actually just realized that it only throws the overflow error when stepping through the code, if I set a breakpoint after that line, it runs to the breakpoint fine, The value of currentZValue is .129394, and BeginRange is 0, and BeginRange + 1 is 0.0015

Comment: You still haven't shared where `BeginRange` is declared and what it is declared as.

Comment: ```BeginRange = 0#``` this makes it a double instead of an (undeclared) variant.

Comment: May be a logic problem but I'm not clear what the intended logic is here.

Comment: If the `CurrentZValue` is <  `BeginRange` then doesn't your loop just keep going until `BeginRange` overflows?